# Canada Income Tax benefits if family is living outside of Canada

Tags: income-tax, canada, ontario

I am working in Toronto, Canada under Work permit. My family is living outside Canada. I am fully taking care of their expenses.

Can I get any income tax benefits for the money I am sending to them?

PS: I am aware of the tax benefits and child care benefits if the family is also living in Canada.

**Update:**

Family in this context - Wife and 2 kids.

Comment: Define 'Family' - are these children, parents, cousins? Are any of them disabled? It seems likely there will be no support for what you are doing, but good to get the details straight.

Comment: Okay for a spouse and children, the definition of whether they depend on you seems to depend on whether they have "enough income or assistance for a reasonable standard of living in the country where they live". Do they truly depend on you for support, or would this be considered an additional 'gift' to them?

Comment: They have zero income and completely dependent on me.

Comment: Not directly but you can claim the tax credit on 303. http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tp/it513r/it513r-e.pdf  I'm not sure about med. expenses, but maybe.